# Should we include "Montenegrin" in the "bosnian-serbian-croatian" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a tag for "bosnian-serbian-croatian' (bsc) for the language that we might have once called *Serbo-Croatian, Croato-Serbia, srpohrvatski* etc.

We use this bsc term now when we discuss those languages based on the Štokavian form of Central South Slavic because three new standards have emerged since the breakup of Yugoslavia, 1992. However, as of 2007 the Montenegrin language has become an official language, so shouldn't the tag be "bosnian-croatian-montenegrin-serbian"?

Without having some term like "Central South Slavic" to cover the wider dialect continuum of these languages, we cannot include 3 of the standards and ignore one of them.

Answer (score 1):

We can't include it since the tag [bosnian-croatian-montenegrin-serbian](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bosnian-croatian-montenegrin-serbian) would be 36 characters long and the maximum for a tag is 25 characters. Unless we find macro-class name, I can't replace it.

Comment: What about BCSM? I guess this might not be clear enough though. bos-cro-mon-ser? Has a ring to it...

Comment: @DangerFourpence I don't know. :D We can wait for more proposals for now and see if there are other ideas.

Comment: What about [tag:south-slavic-languages]?

Comment: @OtavioMacedo That includes other languages too. We can use it, though... Technically these languages here are included in the "Serbo-Croatian standard language" category.

Comment: @OtavioMacedo central-south-slavic-languages would be more accurate, if cumbersome.

Comment: @DangerFourpence yes, but that's 30 characters, which takes us back to the original problem. We can, however, use [tag:central-south-slavic] only (without "-languages").

Comment: Balkan Insight (http://www.balkaninsight.com/en/article/atttackers-on-serb-students-arrested) uses BO-CG-HR-SR, so it seems no one can come up with a very elegant solution

Comment: It's sometimes acceptable for tag names to be inelegant. This is where the tag wiki excerpt and tag synonyms are very helpful. Now ISO 639, the international standard for language codes abolished the unified Serbocroatian codes `sh`/`scr`/`scc`. But there is now an "inclusive" code `hbs` to cover `bos` Bosnian, `hrv` Croatian, `srp` Serbian, and `svm` [Slavomolisano](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slavomolisano). According to Wikipedia Montenegrin doesn't seem to have its own code and uses `srp`, the code for Serbian. Given this mess `hbs` with a tag wiki + excerpt explaining it seems best.

Comment: In the meantime the overwhelmingly most used English word for this language is "Serbocroatian". The fact that term doesn't cover entire countries the language is spoken in might be compared with "English" being the language of "America" etc. Imperfect by one way of analysing it, but widely used and understood nonetheless.